# Graph vertex placement

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

In the following graph I want:

(1) the origin, vertex 1, to be on top;

(2) the ends to be at the same line at the bottom (two are now at a higher level);

(3) to specify that one vertex (vertex 6) should be on the same level as others (vertexes 2, 10, and 11).

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 6, 3 -> 7, 6 -> 8, 6 -> 9,
   7 -> 10, 7 -> 11, 10 -> 12, 10 -> 13, 11 -> 14, 11 -> 15},
 VertexLabels -> {1 -> Placed["Alt?", Center], 
   2 -> Placed[ "One flse postve?", Center], 
   6 -> Placed[ "One flse postve?", Center], 
   3 -> Placed["In database?", Center],
   7 -> Placed["True Positive?", Center], 
   10 -> Placed[ "One flse postve?", Center], 
   11 -> Placed["More positives?", Center],
   4 -> Placed[ "False positive", Center], 
   8 -> Placed[ "False positive", Center], 
   15 -> Placed[ "True positive", Center], 
   12 -> Placed[ "True positive", Center]},
 EdgeLabels -> {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> "Yes", 
   1 \[DirectedEdge] 3 -> "No", 3 \[DirectedEdge] 6 -> "No", 
   3 \[DirectedEdge] 7 -> "Yes", 2 \[DirectedEdge] 4 -> "Yes", 
   2 \[DirectedEdge] 5 -> "No", 7 \[DirectedEdge] 10 -> "No", 
   7 \[DirectedEdge] 11 -> "Yes",
   6 \[DirectedEdge] 8 -> "Yes", 6 \[DirectedEdge] 9 -> "No", 
   10 \[DirectedEdge] 12 -> "Yes", 10 \[DirectedEdge] 13 -> "No", 
   11 \[DirectedEdge] 14 -> "Yes", 11 \[DirectedEdge] 15 -> "No"},
  VertexShapeFunction -> "Square", VertexSize -> {.38, .1}]
```

but now it looks like this, with the origin to the left and the ends on different levels:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the option `GraphLayout->{"LayeredEmbedding","RootVertex" -> 1}` gives a tree with root vertex at node `1`.

```
edgelist = {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 6, 3 -> 7, 6 -> 8, 
  6 -> 9, 7 -> 10, 7 -> 11, 10 -> 12, 10 -> 13, 11 -> 14, 11 -> 15}; 

vlabels = {1 -> Placed["Alt?", Center], 
   2 -> Placed["One flse postve?", Center], 
   6 -> Placed["One false postve?", Center], 
   3 -> Placed["In database?", Center], 
   7 -> Placed["True Positive?", Center], 
   10 -> Placed["One flse postve?", Center], 
   11 -> Placed["More positives?", Center], 
   4 -> Placed["False positive", Center], 
   8 -> Placed["False positive", Center], 
   15 -> Placed["True positive", Center], 
   12 -> Placed["True positive", Center]};
elabels = {(1 -> 2) -> "Yes", (1 -> 3) -> "No", (3 -> 6) -> 
    "No", (3 -> 7) -> "Yes", (2 -> 4) -> "Yes", (2 -> 5) -> 
    "No", (7 -> 10) -> "No", (7 -> 11) -> "Yes", (6 -> 8) -> 
    "Yes", (6 -> 9) -> "No", (10 -> 12) -> "Yes", (10 -> 13) -> 
    "No", (11 -> 14) -> "Yes", (11 -> 15) -> "No"};

options = Sequence[GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "RootVertex" -> 1, 
    LayerSizeFunction -> (1 &), "LeafDistance" -> 2}, 
  VertexLabels -> vlabels, EdgeLabels -> elabels, 
  VertexShapeFunction -> "Rectangle", VertexSize -> {.2, .1}];
g0 = Graph[edgelist, options]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For post-processing `g0` define a function `vcF` to change the corrdinates of selected nodes:

```
ClearAll[vcF]
vcF = #2 -> Property[#2, VertexCoordinates -> {PropertyValue[{#, #2}, 
        VertexCoordinates][[1]], PropertyValue[{#, #3}, VertexCoordinates][[2]]}] &; 

Graph[ VertexList[g0] /. {vcF[g0, 2, 10], vcF[g0, 6, 10], vcF[g0, 9, 15], 
   vcF[g0, 8, 15], vcF[g0, 5, 15], vcF[g0, 4, 15]}, edgelist, options]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update:** Another partial solution is to use the setting `"MultipartiteEmbedding"` for the option `GraphLayout` combined with a vertex list in a specific order:

```
Graph[{1, 3, 7, 2, 6, 10, 11, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15}, edgelist,
 GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> {1, 1, 1, 4, 8}}, 
 VertexLabels -> vlabels, EdgeLabels -> elabels, 
 VertexShapeFunction -> "Square", VertexSize -> {.3, .1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update 2:** You can also specify the vertex coordinates manually:

```
Graph[edgelist, VertexLabels -> vlabels, EdgeLabels -> elabels, 
 VertexShapeFunction -> "Rectangle", VertexSize -> {.6, .2}, 
 VertexCoordinates -> {4 -> {1, 0}, 5 -> {3, 0}, 8 -> {5, 0}, 
   9 -> {7, 0}, 12 -> {9, 0}, 13 -> {11, 0}, 14 -> {13, 0}, 
   15 -> {15, 0}, 2 -> {2, 1}, 6 -> {6, 1}, 10 -> {10, 1}, 
   11 -> {14, 1}, 7 -> {12, 2}, 3 -> {10, 3}, 1 -> {8, 4}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I love the first part, with the `"LayeredEmbedding", "RootVertex" -> 1` because it does what asked in a reasonable fashion. The second part, extracting the coordinates and changing them, is enormously complex. The tree graph functions should have a way to tell Mathematica which vertexes to put on each level rather than having to go inside the graph, reverse engineer the coordinates, and manipulate them. As it is, easier to just make the graph using graphics primitives.

Comment: @NicholasG, I agree with you that a more convenient way to get the desired vertex layout should be possible with built-in layout functions.